# Why i get "Stack object has no attribute Items"?

Tags: object, attributes, runtime, items

```
class Stack():
    def __init___(self):
        self.items = []

    def push(self,item):
        self.items.append(item)

    def pop(self):
        return self.items.pop()

    def get_stack(self):
        return self.items

s = Stack()
s.push("A")
s.push("B")
print(s.get_stack())
```

#stack.py", line 6, in push
self.items.append(item)
AttributeError: 'Stack' object has no attribute 'items'

Comment: You have three "_" after "init", which is why your constructor doesn't get called. Next time you ask something, please tag your question properly. In this case, you would have to add the "python" tag so that people can find your question.

Comment: Thank you very much and will do next time.